# 'Mined block' icon in Windows cmd

Tags: go-ethereum, windows

It might be a trivial detail, but whenever I succesfully mined a block the pickaxe symbol is replaced by '▯▯' in Windows 10 cmd. Why is this? And is there a way to fix it?